# Delay calculation in CMOS devices

Tags: cmos, delay

I've noticed that CMOS delays are only up to 50% of output instead of 100%. Why do some people use 50% delay? Is there an advantage as opposed to 100% delay?

Answer (score 2):

50 % of V<sub>CC</sub> is where a typical CMOS *input* switches, so this corresponds to the time you would observe in an actual circuit.

Furthermore, output waveforms are not perfectly rectangular, and might have ringing:

[image: HA AC AHC slew rate]

So it is not really clear what you would mean with "100 %".
(Similarly, fall and rise times are usually measured between 10 % and 90 %.)

Answer (score 0):

Because once the output reaches about 50% of the full transition it is of sufficient level to cause transitions in downstream gates.  Sometimes 20-80% or other ranges depending on some analysis.

Answer (score -1):

If you view CMOS inverters (one Nch, one Pch, balanced for their amps/volt drive) as amplifiers with gain of 10X, and install 6 in series, you have a gain of 1Million where 5 microVolts PeakPeak at input to the first inverter will cause 5uV * 1Million = 5voltsPP on output of the 6th Inverter.

Almost always this will be an oscillator, because of current thru the final inverter loading down the VDD just a small amount, which affects the 50% point of the very first inverter. Or the fast change in current through that final inverter will cause inductive rail bounce, from Vrailbounce = L * dT/dT. But each of the 6 inverters is switching at its 50% point.